# Trying to find FSX app window

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using C#/winform to try and find the running Microsoft Flight Simulator X window so I can grab the window rect and take a screen shot of it.

However, my code below isn't grabbing the 'fsx' window.

What am I doing wrong?

```
int nWinHandle = FindWindow("Microsoft Flight Simulator X", null);
if (nWinHandle == 0)
{
    this.Text = "not found";
}
else
{
    this.Text = "found";
}
```

Comment: Its unlikely you will be able to grab a screenshot in this manner.  Instead use SimConnect.  SimConnect has a method to take screenshots.

Comment: I looked at the SimConnect SDK and didn't see anything related to taking screen shots...do you by chance have a reference I can look at?

Comment: I do, but its 6000 miles away right now.  I'll post it when I get back next week.

Comment: 2+ years later... also interested to know